# Can you upload a data file in a ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Ipython Notebook to do some data analysis and i'd like to be able to "upload" (really just copy) data files inside the Json Ipython notebook.

This way the Ipython notebook is self contained and doesn't depend on a external file position

As an example

```
with open("Anyfile.dat", "r") as PlainImageFile:
```

Would be something like

```
with fromNotebook("Anyfile.dat") as PlainImageFile:
```

Comment: Well, i can't find anything that does equivalent of what i'm trying to acheive (a self contained notebook: algo + data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible, and it might not even make sens, as the notebook itself might not be on the machine where the kernel runs.

This is not either the goal of the Jupyter/IPython notebook format.

Moreover the kernel as no notion of wether it is runned form inside a notebook, by design. So where would `fromNotebook` look for the data ?

The closest to what you ask is [activePapers](https://khinsen.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/activepapers-for-python/) from Konrad Hinsen, it is a fully contained environment (that also work with notebooks) ment to be fully self contained.

The second option, is to say : 1 git repository for 1 project. You can add data, images, library. [Hashdist](http://hashdist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) also help with that.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware that the example i gave is not complete, what i was thinking of is a way to include an entry in the Json file (containing the data) and an interface to look up that entry and use it in the notebook.

So it may require a %uploadData of some kind

Comment: That will still not be possible. %uploadData will send data to the kernel, which has no information about the `.ipynb` file. What you are trying to do is equivalent to `if get_user().eyes.color == 'blue': ...` it does not make sens, the user can change, or you can even have no user because the kernel is running headless or not from a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

At least in IPython-2 it is possible to implement an *Upload Widget*.

See the examples in these ipynb-notebooks:

- [Upload-widget for IPython-2](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/File%20Upload%20Widget.ipynb).
- [Upload-widget for IPython-3](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/File%20Upload%20Widget.ipynb)